# Javascript algorithm to only show 4 months

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a problem showing the correct months of the year. The problem is that the months don't follow up on each other. I cannot seem to get the algorithm right.

The problem I have at this point that the months don't follow up correctly on each other. Instead of having 'Jan-Feb-Mar-Dec' it should be 'Dec-Jan-Feb-Mar':

[image]

This is the algorithm I have on this point. I can't get my head around how to get the months in correct order when they overlap in different years. The months of the new year are the months in the start of the array:

```
   visibleMonths() {
      let oldestMonth = 0;
      this.months.forEach(month => {
        if (month.visible && month.value > oldestMonth)
          oldestMonth = month.value;
      });
      if (oldestMonth + 4 > 11) {
          let visibleMonths = [];
        // ORDER THE MONTHS 
      } else {
        return this.months.filter(month => month.visible === true);
      }
    }
```

```
months: [
        { name: "Jan", value: 0, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Feb", value: 1, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Mar", value: 2, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Apr", value: 3, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Mei", value: 4, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Jun", value: 5, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "jul", value: 6, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Aug", value: 7, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Sep", value: 8, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Okt", value: 9, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Nov", value: 10, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Dec", value: 11, active: false, visible: false }
      ],
```

Comment: can you provide your `months` array?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the array.

Comment: Do you want to have a rotating list of months? In that case, always having all months in a fixed array and toggling visibility will not work since the months will always stay in order from Jan to Dec. Would obtaining a new array containing only the visible moths be a valid option? In this case I could provide a simple method (don't call it _'algorithm'_ please, that's a big word ;)).

Comment: I am using Vue. This function is inside the computed vue function. So it is an new array.

Comment: If you want wrap-around, don't have just months in that array. Generate year-month combinations. Order those by year and month.

Comment: If `visible` is alternating false and true, you will still have gaps, right? What is the role of `visible`? Is it relevant to the question? What if only two months have `visible` true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply shift your source array and append it to temporary array which you can `slice` afterwards:

```js
const months = [
        { name: "Jan", value: 0, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Feb", value: 1, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Mar", value: 2, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Apr", value: 3, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Mei", value: 4, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Jun", value: 5, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "jul", value: 6, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Aug", value: 7, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Sep", value: 8, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Okt", value: 9, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Nov", value: 10, active: false, visible: false },
        { name: "Dec", value: 11, active: false, visible: false }
      ]
const currentMonthIndex = new Date().getMonth()

function getVisibleMonths(months, currentMonthIndex) {
  const tmp = [...months]
  const res = []
  for (i = 0; i < currentMonthIndex; i++) {
    res.push(tmp.shift())
  }
  return [...tmp, ...res].slice(0, 4)
}

console.log(getVisibleMonths(months, currentMonthIndex))
```